# Convergence in distribution absolute value of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

How to proof from definition of convergence in distribution that fact:

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, . . .$ and $X$ be real random variables with
respective distribution functions $F_{X_1}, F_{X_2}, . . .$ and $F_{X}$. If $X_{n}$ converges in distribution to random variable $X$ then $|X_{n}|$ converge in distribution to $|X|$.

We say that sequence of random variable $X_{1}, X_{2}, . . .$ converges in distribution to $X$ if and only if $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n}(x)=F_{X}(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ at which $F_X$ is continuous.

I will be very grateful for the tips.

Comment: What have you tried ? Also your definition of convergence in distribution is wrong as stated. It holds for continuous variables, but you need to account for continuity points of $F_X$ otherwise.

Comment: $P(|X_n| \leq x)=P(X_n \leq x, X_n \geq 0)+P(-X_n \leq x, X_n <0)$ but here I can't use the assumption

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the definition.

Comment: Hint: For $x\ge 0$ we have $\Pr\{|X_n| \le x\} = \Pr\{ X_n \le x \} - \Pr\{ X_n < -x \}$.

Answer (score -1):

Going by the comment, \begin{align*}
\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{\vert X_n \vert } (x) &= \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\vert X_n \vert \leq x) \\ 
&= \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(-x \leq  X_n  \leq x) \\ 
&=  \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{ P(X_n \leq x) - P(X_n < -x) \} \\ 
&= \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n \leq x) - \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n < -x) \\ 
&= P(X \leq x) - P(X < -x) = P(\vert X \vert \leq x),
\end{align*}
where the fourth inequality follows by the algebraic properties of limits.